# Firebase Cloud Messaging's getToken() only works if I omit the usePublicVapidKey method, why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, vapid

I'm having a specific issue with the implementation of Firebase for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM):

As you can see in the code below, `//messaging.usePublicVapidKey("<MY VAPID KEY IN HERE>");` is currently commented. The VAPID key was obtained with the command: `web-push generate-vapid-keys` in the server's terminal. If I uncomment this line, I get this error in the console when I call `notification_permission()`:

- **code: "messaging/token-subscribe-failed",**
- **message: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",**
- **stack: "FirebaseError: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-messaging.js:6:8316"**

This is my current `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "<MY FIREBASE API KEY>",
    authDomain: "<MY FIREBASE PROJECT ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<MY FIREBASE PROJECT ID>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<MY FIREBASE PROJECT ID>",
    storageBucket: "<MY FIREBASE PROJECT ID>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<MY FIREBASE SENDER ID?>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//messaging app
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

//vapid
//messaging.usePublicVapidKey("<MY VAPID KEY IN HERE>");

//register service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Service Worker Registered!', registration);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Service Worker registration failed', err);
});
</script>
```

This is the javascript function I call to get the user's permission to receive notifications and get the user's token:

```
<script>
function notification_permission() {
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.', permission);
        messaging.getToken().then(function(current_token) {
            if(current_token) {
                //update user token
                // update_token(current_token);
                console.log('token', current_token);
            } else {
                // you don't have permission to show notifications
                // detect whether they are blocked or not, then show your custom UI
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // retrieving token failed, analyze the error
            console.error('retrieving token failed, analyze the error', err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err)
    });
}
</script>
```

I already have this on my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507",
    "serviceworker": {
        "src": "firebase-messaging-sw.js",
        "scope": "/"
    }
}
```

My specific questions with this configuration are:

1. Is it ok to use `web-push generate-vapid-keys` to get a VAPID key just once, and the use that very same VAPID key for all user requests?
2. Why is the `getToken()` method failing when using the VAPID key?
3. Is the VAPID method optional? What are the advantages of using it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a inverse situation, when I omit VAPID key then I couldn't get token,it gives the same error that you mentioned as requiring "OAUTH2"

If I add a VAPID key, then I can take a token but when I send a notification, it does not receive any message.

I'm searching for that but couldn't find any related doc.

Should I use VAPID key, if so what may be wrong with not receiving a message
or should I not use that key, then what should I do to get a token without requiring OAUTH2? 
I hope you resolved already.

Answer (score 1):

1) yes.

2) because the token is related to firebase account and not the vapid key. Bypassing firebase you can't get any token.

3) using vapid is useful when NOT using firebase.

Comment: I don't know if maybe this has changed since you responded, but it seems as though vapid IS useful WITH firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_web_credentials_in_your_app